# Textbox numbers only with "-"

Tags: textbox

I have this code, but I want to be able to use negative numbers too, but with this code I can't use "-"
I've looked at keys enumeration, but I can't find it on that page.

```
    private void tbInvoerEuros1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) 
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;


        if e.Handled = !(Char.IsDigit(ch) || (ch == '-') || (ch < ' ') && ch != 46 && ch != 8));
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but did you even try something ? Apparently not cause this question is very trivial...

Comment: I don't even see anywhere any hint to which language/framework/whatsoever, except for the code snippet.

Comment: Sorry for being noob at c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution (based on your code) may look this:

```
private void tbInvoerEuros1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  char ch = e.KeyChar;

  // Stop processing character unless it 
  //   - digit
  //   - minus sign
  //   - command character (e.g. BackSpace, Enter, Escape)
  // (ch < ' ') better than (ch != 8) because you'd probably want to 
  // preserve commands like ENTER (13), ESCAPE (27), SHIFT TAB (15) etc.
  e.Handled = !(Char.IsDigit(ch) || (ch == '-') || (ch < ' '));
}
```

But you'd probably have to take into account some issues:

1. User can paste text in your textbox, so you have to do with TextChanged event
2. Minus sign seems to be a special symbol: if, e.g. user put "1", "2", "-" you'd probably   should put it like "-12", not "12-"

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But it didn't work, I edited the code with the code you told me please take a look at it ;)

Comment: Well, it does work as designed (I've tested it): the code prevents user from processing keys other than 0..9, '-' and command ones. 
If user press, say, 'A' is it'll not appear in the textbox. Elaboreted version should also prevent, IMHO, from pasting, say,
"A" from clipboard into the textbox and should include special '-' processing.